# Why does a number of completed tasks in Mapreduce decrease?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When running hadoop jobs, I noticed that sometimes the number of completed tasks decreases and number of canceled tasks increases.

How is this possible? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

I've only experienced this when our cluster was in a strange state, so I'm not sure if this is the same issue. Basically, map tasks would complete, and then the reducers would start... and then mappers would be reprocessed.

I believe that the problem is that mapper output hangs around on that data node waiting for reducers to pick it up. If that node has issues or it dies, the JobTracker decides that it needs to rerun that task again, even if it had completed. Our issue was that the system our NameNode was on was having some non-Hadoop related issues and once those were resolves it seemed to go away.

Sorry if my experience was not relevant to your issue. Perhaps, can you post more details? Do you see any error messages? Is there anything weird in your JobTracker or NameNode logs?